# How to use modify_if to divide each numeric column by another column?

Tags: r, purrr

I want to divide each column in dataframe which satisfy a condition by one of the columns within the same dataframe

I believe it can be done in several ways, but I feel that it would be more efficient for me if I could do it using purrr package which is designed for this type of work.

for example, this works

```
t <- iris %>% 
  modify_if(is.numeric, ~./2)
```

but this does not

```
t <- iris %>% 
  modify_if(is.numeric, ~./Sepal.Length)
```

this results in error

```
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'Sepal.Length' not found
```

I think it wants me to specify .y as "Sepal.Length" but I could not figure out the right way.

I am confused between modify2, imodify, map2 and pmap

I would appreciate if you can point me to a proper guide on how to use purrr properly. The official guide seems to be okay for the concept and intuition
 but I am struggling to put it in application. 
https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/modify.html

Comment: For me (dplyr-0.8.1), this works without error: `iris %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ ./Sepal.Length)`.

Comment: @r2evans that does work without error but if you examine the results, only the `Sepal.Length` column is correct. This is because it's the first column, so it divides by itself to give 1 and then all other columns are divided by 1 _i.e._ unchanged.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I read `modify_if` and thought `mutate_if`, ...

Comment: You could use `mutate_if` if the columns were reordered to place `Sepal.Length` last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `modify_if` in this case, we can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

iris %>% modify_if(is.numeric, ~./iris$Sepal.Length)

#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#1              1   0.6862745    0.2745098  0.03921569     setosa
#2              1   0.6122449    0.2857143  0.04081633     setosa
#3              1   0.6808511    0.2765957  0.04255319     setosa
#4              1   0.6739130    0.3260870  0.04347826     setosa
#5              1   0.7200000    0.2800000  0.04000000     setosa
#6              1   0.7222222    0.3148148  0.07407407     setosa
#....
```

Or another version

```
iris %>%  modify_if(is.numeric, function(x) x/.$Sepal.Length)
```

Or as suggested by @Artem Sokolov

```
iris %>% modify_if(is.numeric, `/`, .$Sepal.Length)
```

---

Another way to do it would be using `mutate_if` , however for that you need to rearrange the columns as mentioned by @neilfws

```
iris %>%
  select(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Species, Sepal.Length) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, ~./Sepal.Length)
```

---

and finally using base R

```
iris[] <- lapply(iris, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) x/iris$Sepal.Length else x)
#OR
cols <- sapply(iris, is.numeric)
iris[cols] <- lapply(iris[cols], function(x) x/iris$Sepal.Length)
```

Comment: Yet another version: ``iris %>% modify_if(is.numeric, `/`, .$Sepal.Length)``

Comment: @ArtemSokolov   I think this might be the solution I am looking for. Can you please edit it with explicit arguments like ```iris %>% modify_if(.p = is.numeric, .f = `/`, .y = .$Sepal.Length)```